# what is "DGA allocated (under PGA)" and "maximum DGA allocated" in the view V$PGASTAT?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle21c

in oracle 21c there is no mention of DGA and what it does, I couldn't find anything anywhere else.

what is DGA? and what are it's uses ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the "dynamic global area".  It's a pool of variables that are initialized when the PGA initializes and are not changeable.  Putting them in a shared space allows all your database processes to access them, like global variables.  I think these variables must be initialized prior to SGA initialization, which is perhaps why they're in PGA and not in SGA.

I don't think you can use DGA in your application code, nor do I think you can tune its size.  I think only Oracle features can use it.

This is my understanding based on very limited information that's available.